# JQuery and Ajax calls on newly created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic-content

I am fairly new to Ajax and JQuery and have been doing a ton of reading and cannot find a solution that will work for me.

I have a JQuery `on.click` trigger calling an function via `Ajax` to update my page without reloading it entirely.  However, **these new elements being created cannot have this function triggered on it as well.**

The function below essentially adds a `<tr>` to the end of a `table`.  This new `<tr>`'s `<a>` elements added cannot trigger this same function after the  has been added.

```
$("a.add-department").on( "click", function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.dialog({
        message: '<form class="form-horizontal row-border"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name:</label><div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" id="department-name-add" value="" class="form-control"></div></div></form>',
        title: "Add a Department",
        buttons: {
            success: {
                label: "Add",
                className: "btn-success",
                callback: function() {
                    var name = $("#department-name-add").val();;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/departments/add",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: 'name=' + name,
                        success: function(result){
                            if (result.success == 1)
                            {
                                $('#table-departments > tbody:last').append('<tr id="'+result.id+'"><td id="td-'+result.id+'">'+result.name+'</td><td id="td-actions-'+result.id+'"><a data-name="'+result.name+'" data-id="'+result.id+'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete-department confirm-dialog">Delete</a> <a id="a-edit-'+result.id+'" data-name="'+result.name+'" data-id="'+result.id+'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary edit-department">Edit</a></td></tr>');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(result){
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            danger: {
                label: "Cancel",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function() {
                    console.log('Cancelled Request');
                }
            },
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried a combination of using .on versus just .click as well as tying id's to each element.

Any thoughts?

Also, I know the code is most likely considered ugly, I am just trying to understand how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: new appended html does not have any element anchor tag with class add-department

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - Good eye, however I did not include the entire scope (too large).  I have another listener for the class edit-department to launch a modal window attached to a separate form and function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use event delegation instead. That way new elements added can trigger the event.

Here is a link to learn more about event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
Event delegation looks like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.add-department", callback)
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to do [**event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) if the elements are loaded dynamically via ajax, as you are appending html in table with id `table-departments` you can use that this way :

```
$("#table-departments").on("click", "a.add-department", function(){



})
```

and for edit:

```
 $("#table-departments").on("click", "a.edit-department", function(){



    })
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I was able to just copy my function in between your answer and it worked.  I never really knew about delegation.

Comment: @evade welcome and now you know about delgation right..:) feel free to accept my answer..